# Multidimensional Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I'm wondering if it is possible to perform a multidimensional matrix multiplication without resorting to a for-loop. Given the N-by-P matrix A and the N-by-M-by-P matrix B, I want to compute the M-dimensional vector y, defined element-wise as

```
y(j) = sum_(i = 1,...,N) sum_(k = 1,...,P) A(i,k)*B(i,j,k)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can linearize `A` into a row vector, then [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the array `B` as a matrix, so that the desired result is just matrix multiplication:

```
M = 5;
N = 6;
P = 8;
A = rand(N,P);
B = rand(N,M,P);
result = A(:).'*reshape(permute(B, [1 3 2]), [], M);
```

---

Or `reshape` matrix `A` so that its dimensions are aligned with those of `B`, use [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to multiply with singleton-expansion, and sum over the two desired dimensions:

```
result = sum(sum(bsxfun(@times, reshape(A, N, 1, P), B), 1), 3);
```